# Magento admin redirects to 404 page after login

Tags: magento

I'm struggling to set up Magento 1.9.1 on Godaddy for the few hours. I've managed to get all URLs work, except admin, which renders a 404 page with Magento's "Whoops" message just after logging in with the right password.

The URI: `/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/b4a2c39042dae9efe5b17e98e93d5f64/`

Changing the core library files as suggested in other topics didn't make any difference.

Comment: uncomment #   Options -MultiViews in .htaccess

Comment: Did you check that id values of 0 exist? E.g. in table `core_website` the field `website_id` where `code` is `admin` has a 0 value?

Comment: nope. why should they exist right after a clean installation?

Comment: They did after my recent 1.9 installation.

Comment: have you try to access admin without index.php
/admin/dashboard/index/key/b4a2c39042dae9efe5b17e98e93d5f64/

if it works then try with this extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-rewrites.html
it should help you..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble, I have resolved it editing .htaccess. My Magento installation is in a subdirectory of my hosting. I have removed the # on the RewriteBase line and added the right value for the subdirectory.

in .htaccess :

```
RewriteBase /magento_directory/
```